# How to stick contents of div to the top of the div?

Tags: html, css, button, textarea, vertical-alignment

I want to have a `paragraph`, next to a `button`, next to a `textarea` element. I've made that, but now, when I expand the `textarea`, the button moves down too. I want to have a button and a paragraph that sticks to the top of the `div` it's in, so it must not be affected by the height of the textarea.

*I know there has to be a very simple solution to this problem, but I couldn't find it :(*

This is my code:

```css
#textarea {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#p {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <p id="p">Random Text</p>
  <button id="button">Button</button>
  <textarea id="textarea">
    Random
    Text
  </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `vertical-align: top;` for `p` and `button`

Comment: I _knew_ it was easy, I just didn't know of the `vertical-align` property! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `vertical-align:top` for `p` and `button`

```css
#textarea {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#p {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
p,button{
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <p id="p">Random Text</p>
  <button id="button">Button</button>
  <textarea id="textarea">
    Random
    Text
  </textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

see comment in answer.. set all children on #parent to align to top

```css
#textarea {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#p {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

/* i added this */
#parent > * {
  vertical-align:  top;
  }
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <p id="p">Random Text</p>
  <button id="button">Button</button>
  <textarea id="textarea">
    Random
    Text
  </textarea>
</div>
```